# The role of comma in the syntax of `Part`

Tags: expression-manipulation

I can't understand the syntax of `Part`, namely what does `,` do. The documentation says that

```
expr[[i,j,...]] or Part[expr,i,j,...]
is equivalent to expr[[i]][[j]]...
```

however when I do

```
m = RandomInteger[9, {3, 4}];
m[[All, 2]] == m[[All]][[2]]
```

I get `False`.

Comment: `All` is special in this case, because `m[[All]]` is just `m`, and so `m[[All,2]]` being the second column of the matrix is not equal to `m[[All]][[2]]`, which is the second row.

Comment: Don't be too quick to trust the documentation when it says something is equivalent to something else. More often than not, it's not true. Here the intent is just to say that values separated by commas apply to the successive levels of the expressions, so it's unfortunate that the documentation references a false equivalence that just causes confusion. Maybe it should say "generically equivalent"--i.e., without taking into account special values, or performance characteristics.

Comment: `m == m[[All]]`, `m[[1, 2]] == m[[1]][[2]]`.

Comment: Note that `m[[All]] == m` is True and so `m[[All]][[2]] == m[[2]]` is also True

Comment: The documentation also shows [another situation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bueuq-73wfiy) in which these are not equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your misunderstanding of how `Part` works has nothing to do with comma, which is simply a delimiter (arguably the only delimiter *Mathematica* has). The documentation is correct when it says "`expr[[i, j, ... ]]` or `Part[expr, i, j, ...]` is equivalent to `expr[[i]][[j]]...` " providing the indices `i`, `j`, .. all represent integers. In `Part`, the **position** of the indices in `Part` determine the level at which the index should be applied. For example, `m[[2, 3]]` extracts  2nd element at level 1 of `m` and then extracts the 3rd element from that (which was at level 2 in `m`). Thus,

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {c, d, e}};
m[[2, 3]] == m[[2]][[3]] == e
```

`All` is a special token that, when it appears in `Part`, tells *Mathematica* to effectively map `Part` at that level. That is,

```
m[[All, 3]]
```

> `{c, e}`

is effectively the same as

```
Part[#, 3] & /@ m
```

and

```
m[[All, {1, 3}]]
```

> `{{a, c}, {c, e}}`

is effectively the same as

```
Part[#, {1, 3}] & /@ m
```